# Displaying a full path as ellipsed, shorter path

Tags: .net, string, vb.net

I need to display a path in a button.
For example, this path might be

```
"c:\users\myuser\desktop\somefolder"
```

The button has a fixed size, therefore I'm looking for a way to convert the text to an ellipsed version.

I think I remember seeing a function that would convert such a long path to something like

```
"c:\users\...\somefolder"
```

But I don't remember if it was a custom solution or if there's a built-in way to do that in .NET.

I don't mean the ShortPath function that would turn the string into

```
"c:\users\myuser\deskto~"
```

Thank you.

Comment: It was a custom solution. The result is an invalid path that's only useful for display.

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation might look something like this:

```
var pathString = @"c:\users\myuser\desktop\somefolder";
var maxStringLength = 25;

while(pathString.Length > maxStringLength)
{
    var splitPath = pathString.Split('\\').ToList();
    splitPath.Remove("...");
    splitPath[splitPath.Count - 2] = "...";
    pathString = string.Join("\\", splitPath);
}
```

Keep in mind, that this has a very naïve view of what constitutes a path. You might find that you need to change it, and write appropriate tests, depending on your needs.